# Create a new object each loop

Tags: c#, list, while-loop

I have a while loop inside a database connection, where I want to create an object from the values retrieved from the database. 
This is the code I used:

```
 public void dbConnect()
    {
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=CHAYU\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=restaurantApp; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30"))
        {

            string oString = "Select * from Meal where availability=1";
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    Meal m = new Meal();
                    m.mealID = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["mealId"]);
                    m.mealName = oReader["mealName"].ToString();
                    m.quantity=Convert.ToInt32(oReader["quantity"]);
                    m.timeToProduce = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["timeToProduce"]);
                    m.availability = true;


                }

                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to call this code each time the form loads, so that the objects are created at the beginning, and they can later be manipulated. But, my problem is, how do I do so, by having a different reference variable to the object, inside the while loop?

Comment: Your question isn't clear... but it sounds like you should be creating a collection...

Comment: Don't use select * PLS, only select what you need.

Comment: @Praveen Definitely not ArrayList!

Comment: @dcastro Thanks for correcting me. Indeed i went wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to have each meal? Create a list and store your meal objects while iterating in it!

```
List<Meal> mList = new List<Meal>();
while (oReader.Read())
{
    Meal m = new Meal();
    m.mealID = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["mealId"]);
    m.mealName = oReader["mealName"].ToString();
    m.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["quantity"]);
    m.timeToProduce = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["timeToProduce"]);
    m.availability = true;
    mList.Add(m);
}
```

Comment: If I want to edit the attribute values of the object, can I do so after it is in List?

Comment: yes, access it by it's index `mList[0].mealName = "Fish";` or by Linq `mList.Where(x => x.mealID== 10).First().mealName = "Chips";`

Answer (score 0):

Add each created object in the loop to a List. By default each Meal being created in your loop is a different reference, but you're not storing them anywhere to manipulate later.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension method Get list of object in your datareder class

```
public static List<T> DataReaderMapToList<T>(IDataReader dr)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    T obj = default(T);
    while (dr.Read()) {
        obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            if (!object.Equals(dr[prop.Name], DBNull.Value)) {
                prop.SetValue(obj, dr[prop.Name], null);
            }
        }
        list.Add(obj);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then use it  like this

```
List<Meal> MealList = new List<Meal>();
MealList = DataReaderMapToList<Meal>(reader);
```